Python4delphi use external Python library
I want to integrate Python libraries into an Android application in a Delphi environment. In general, to run a Python environment in an Android application, the environment must first be embedded and loaded from within Delphi by selecting Python and the version type. Then, it is eventually integrated with the application and appears in the form of an SO file.
What I am trying to do is figure out how to install any external Python library and run it in an Android application using Delphi.
I tried installing the MoviePy library through this link: https://github.com/Embarcadero/PythonPackages4Delphi/tree/main/src/MoviePy but it didn’t work. I also tried the attached project: https://github.com/Embarcadero/P4D-Data-Sciences/tree/main/samples/InstallAndImport which includes the PyTorch library. Both have the properties autoImport, autoInstall set to true, and the MoviePy and PyTorch components are set up by default as I stated earlier, with the addition of pythonEngine and pyEmbeddedEnvironment.
But neither worked.
The problem is the same: the same message appears, which is that when executing the isImported function, it returns the value false.
When running the application, the library is supposed to be installed and imported, but this didn’t happen even when the phone was connected to the internet.
